# Unable to ping out to Internet from Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, amazon-ec2

I am configuring an NTP server running Ubuntu 14 remotely, but it is not reaching to any timeservers, so I tried to troubleshoot it and discovered that the server is not getting ping responses from any host on the Internet. Example google.com but it is pinging to localhost. All inbound and outbound rules in security group and ACl is allowed. UFW is inactive and no rule in iptables.

And yes, I am able to ssh to this server, so it was on the network.

**Output of ping**

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.7.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
59 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 58007ms
```

Comment: show actual output of ping.  Even the failure messages, it has several of them (and a mode where no error message is seen), it's so useful :).    tell us if you are accessing the server using SSH successfully already, or if instead you are using some access method which does not require network.  My first guess was DNS; if `ping` shows failure to resolve host then show `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.  `getent ahosts google.com` can also be useful to confirm failure.

Comment: If it is not dns, then `sudo traceroute -T google.com` can be useful.

Comment: _always_ share the specific error messages, if you can see them.  Or if there is no message.  Or if the program sits there doing nothing despite you waiting 60 seconds, say that.

Comment: Probably you dont have the default gateway configured on the server. Try something like "route" without any arguments and this will show your default gateway.

Comment: If you're really got no rules in `iptables` (it would be nice to know - `iptables -nvL` please) then Amazon has set you up with a firewall that allows inbound `ssh` and nothing else.

Comment: What do you mean when you say, “it is pinging to localhost”? Do you mean that ``ping localhost`` works normally (i.e., it succeeds)? If so, it’s good to know, but it doesn’t really prove much.